# build fatjar only with class used

Tags: java, build

Is there a maven plugin that will package all libraries I use ( like fatjar ) but it only includes the class that I  used, so that I don't need to care about issues like log4j vulnerability if I don't use JNDI?

Comment: That is usually not possible (especially not for libraries like log4j), as they usually rely on reflection and runtime configuration, making it impossible to decide at compile/assembly time what actually gets used or not. In any case, asking for tool suggestions is off-topic.

Comment: I see, thanks, btw where is a good place to ask for tool suggestions?